# Why the"n" in "Monday" and "Sunday" is pronounced sounding like "/ŋ/" rather than "/n/" displayed in the dictionary?

Tags: phonology

I look up some dictionaries the phonogram of  "n" in these words are marked as "/n/". But I just found the pronunciation sounds like "/ŋ/". I don't know why.

Comment: I’m American and I definitely hear (and pronounce) /n/, and not at all /ŋ/. Where are you hearing people pronounce Monday and Sunday this way? What gives you the impression that it’s pronounced so? Do you have links to videos or audio recordings? If not, why country or region are you in where native speakers of English pronounce /ŋ/? Are you perhaps hearing non-native speakers pronounce these words? If so, what is their common mother tongue?

Comment: Bron, I use an electronic dictionary software, and there are some recordings from America or Britain. There is a link https://www.macmillandictionary.com/pronunciation/british/sunday, I just find it sounds like /ŋ/? Maybe my native language Chinese has some influence on my hearing.

Comment: sumelic, my native language is Chinese.

Comment: @K.K That particular recording unambiguously sounds like an /n/ to me. Also, just so you know, in Western culture, our names are “GivenName FamilyName”, so my given name is “Dan” and my family name, the one I inherited from my father, is “Bron”. In informal contexts like the web, we typically address each other by our given names, so instead of calling me “Bron”, you’d usually refer to me as “Dan”.

Comment: Are you sure you mean velar [ŋ], as in _sing_ or _hang_, and not [ɳ], the retroflex nasal found in many Indian languages? Many Indian languages have dental as well as retroflex stops and nasals, but English has alveolar ones, which are kind of halfway between dentals and retroflexes. For this reason, many speakers of Indian languages substitute retroflexes for the alveolars and may well pronounce /n/ as [ɳ]. But I have never heard anyone, from anywhere in the world, pronounce _Monday_ with a velar [ŋ].

Comment: @Dan Bron, thank you. Maybe because the /n/ is in the middle, it sounds like /ŋ/? I can clearly hear /n/ in sun, but not in Sunday.

Comment: @K.K What Chinese specificly? It might help with our research.

Comment: @A Lambent Eye In many China regions, we can be easily confused with the /n/ and /ŋ/. I just realized the difference after I have learned English for about 10 years. As for specific region, maybe Gansu, Shan'xi, Hunan people there maybe have the same problem.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet I am not very certain it is /ŋ/. I don't know Indian accent. But I found the "n" in "Sunday" is not so clear as "n" in "sun".

Comment: @K.K Many Mandarin speakers (and probably also speakers of other Chinese languages) have difficulties pronouncing /n/ at the end of a syllable as an actual nasal consonant. It becomes a nasalised vowel followed by something like [ð̞̃] (basically almost an n, but where the tongue doesn’t quite touch the alveolar ridge). The same is true of final /ŋ/ which becomes [ɰ̃]. This may be what’s interfering with how you hear the sounds. The n in _sun_ is likely to be longer than the one in _Sunday_ if spoken in isolation, but they are otherwise pronounced identically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are probably hearing /ŋ/ as a kind of auditory illusion. The sequence [ŋd] is phonetically possible, and it is possible for [nd] to develop to [ŋd] (this has occurred in certain Romance languages), but I don't know of any evidence of this happening in English.

I have read that in quick speech, a nasal consonant before a homorganic plosive in English may be realized mostly as nasalization of the preceding vowel. (E.g. see "Vowel Nasality as a Distinctive Feature in American English", by André Malécot, 1960.) Perhaps you are hearing a pronunciation of /mʌndeɪ/ that has a nasalized vowel and no clear nasal consonant— something like [mə̃deɪ]. (Actually, I think nasalized vowels in English are usually only "partly" nasalized, so a more narrow transcription might be something like [məə̃deɪ]. But note that [məə̃] here is only one syllable, not two.)

I believe that syllables ending in /ŋ/ in Chinese are often pronounced with nasalized vowels rather than a coda nasal consonant, so certain nasalized vowels might sound to you like they contain /ŋ/ even though they really don't. (Similarly, I think that English speakers sometimes hear an illusory /ŋ/ in the nasal vowels of French, judging by impressionistic transcriptions like "rahng-day-voo" for the French pronunciation of *rendez-vous*.)

Comment: Syllables ending in both /n/ and /ŋ/ in Chinese (at least Mandarin) are usually pronounced with at least partially nasalised vowels, and the actual consonant is usually reduced to a nasalised approximant as well (dentoalveolar or velar, respectively). This produces a much stronger ‘cumulative nasalisation’ than the fairly facultative one present in English, and I think it’s likely the Chinese tendency towards nasalisation is playing a bigger part in the auditory illusion here than the English one.

Answer (score -1):

At least when using Received Pronunciation ('official' British English), it is quite clearly an /n/.

I wouldn't find it surprising for some non-English accents to pronounce a sound closer to a /ŋ/ though. Otherwise it would be quite a clear /n/.

Comment: A valid question. What I meant was velar, but I couldn't remember the terminology. I was thinking perhaps a more Indian accent? As far as I'm aware there are accents there that are stretched in that sort of a direction, but I couldn't be sure. I imagined saying 'sing', then taking 'Monday' and making the /n/ a /ŋ/, and it didn't sound impossible.

Comment: @ALambentEye It seems impossible to my ear (AmE). It would render “Mungday” or “Sungday”, as far as I’m able to voice it; it seems to require some accommodation from the preceding vowel. And no accent I’m aware of actually does this. I’m trying to picture an IndE speaker doing this, but it doesn’t seem to fit. Something about it suggest Chinese to me, but that’s just a nebulous feeling without any real thought behind it. Maybe because I had a native Chinese math prof in college who pronounced “zero” as “gero” or maybe “gyro”.